# Can't assign result of Array#filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to assign the results of a filter on the array. For some reason it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing?

[image]

Edit:

[image]

Edit 2:

```
  allSegmentNotes = () => {
    let field = `${this.props.segment}Notes`
    let reservationsWithNotes = this.props.allReservations.filter(reservation => !!reservation[field] )

    return (
      reservationsWithNotes.map(
        (reservation, i) => {
          return <p key={i}>{reservation[field]}</p>
        }
      )
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us what `this.props.allReservations` returns? And what `field` is? Show some example data so we can see what is going wrong with your filter.

Comment: Actual code instead of screenshots would make it easier to manipulate and therefore provide an answer.

Comment: I think whatever I'm seeing above might be an issue with the chrome js console. There's sometimes a pretty big disconnect between what I write in React, and the code actually running in the browser. I miss being able to run the debugger, but it just isn't useful much in React... :( I think this is actually working though in my code... Should probably delete the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome dev tools has problems with the scope of variables you create in it. If you write `let x=5` you create a local variable in some context, and if you write `x`, you try to read a variable from possibly a different place, e.g. `window.x`. I'm not sure why, but sometimes by `x` you will reach your `let x` variable, but sometimes, especially when waiting at a breakpoint, you won't - you'll just see `windows.x` which is undefined.

The workaround when debugging in dev tools is not to use `let` at all, just `reservationsWithNotes=this.props.allReservations.filter(...)`. Then the result will be assigned to `window.reservationsWithNotes` and you'll be able to obtain it by just writing `reservationsWithNotes`. Of course this pollutes the global namespace, but during debugging you really don't care.

Anyway, it definitely has nothing to do with `Array#filter`.